# How to use instance subscript in Swift Tabular Data to access DataFrame Column as an Array

Tags: swift

I am attempting to turn a Swift TabularData DataFrame column into an array. The Apple Developer Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/dataframe/subscript(_:_:)-6oqm0) describes the following Instance Subscript that does exactly that:

`subscript<T>(columnName: String, type: T.Type = T.self) -> [T?] { get set }`

However, when I attempt to the following code on a DataFrame (named elevationsDf) with a column (named "PLoss"), it returns a `Column<Double>` instead of a `[Double]`.

`print(type(of: elevationsDf["PLoss", Double.self]))`

What should I change to address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `DataFrame` also has [this subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/dataframe/subscript(_:_:)-5walz):

```
subscript<T>(columnName: String, type: T.Type) -> Column<T> { get set }
```

And that is what your code resolves to.

To call the subscript that you want, you can specify the type of the result explicitly:

```
let c: [Int?] = df["a", Int.self]
```

Or just:

```
let c: [Int?] = df["a"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized subscripting was overloaded like that!